# cannot able to run react native project by android emulator

Tags: react-native

[Error when try to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JiMi.jpg)

I am having react native project and iam trying on android emulator via below command

```
react-native run-android
```

but its not working getting the error like in the image

Answer (score 0):

From your log, it's clear that you haven't configured SDK location
You must add SDK location

```
sdk.dir=/Users/XXXXX/Library/Android/sdk
```

1. Create a new file named local.properties inside the android folder of your react-native app.
2. Add the SDK location.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi,
If you want to fix this for next projects you can create a env variable nammed "ANDROID_HOME" with SDK location.

Comment: Why should we need to do this ?

Comment: I have done that !! , but still the problem persists